# Looking for a json key/value backend application

Tags: json, database

I have a website and it stores users shoppingcarts in a cookie. Now turns out they have a 4k limit so I wanted to use localStorage. Our website uses wildcard domains and so that doesn't work either. I saw hacks using a iframe however that isn't an option.

I have a possible solution and that is to store the shoppingcart (in json) in a database through a backend application. We don't need security just a simple solution where we can persist and read json in the form of a key/value pair to and from a endoint. The key being a unique uuid for that session/user and the value being the shoppingcart. Is there a solution like this?

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is! You've got a few options, including Flask (Python), Express (node.js). For either, if you're trying to go the simple way, you can actually just create a json file and query it from the server.

Comment: And what database would you recommend for the saving of the json? Prefably a key/value paid database. I saw Redis is suitable for the job. Would you recommand that one?

Comment: Well, I'm no expert at this, so take my suggestion with a grain of salt, but a NoSQL setup would also work, depending on the scale of the project, a `.json` file would also work, but that's not so good for scalability. A basic MySQL setup would also suffice as your data does not seem relational. 
If you'd like assistance with the endpoint, feel free to reach out and contact me.